# Calculate convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

We are given $X_1,X_2,...$which are all independent random variables and have $Exp(\ln n)$ distribution. Our task is to show that this random variables converge to 0 with probability but not almost surely. I am hitting a wall with this one. What should be my approach here?

Comment: Could you word this in a more understandable way?

Comment: This one is trivial, take the probability density function and prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_x^{\infty} p_n(x)dx =0$. This then, tends to the $\delta$ distribution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Recall the definition of convergence in probability: $X_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$ means that for each $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Can you compute $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon)$ explicitly?

To show that there isn't almost sure convergence, show that for some $\epsilon > $, $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon \text{ infinitely often}) = 1$.  How do you show that something happens infinitely often?

Comment: Thanks, you save my day ! So $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon)=e^{-\ln n \epsilon}=n^{-\epsilon}$. And it converges to $0$ for every positive $\epsilon$ Now since $X_1,X_2...$ are independent we may use Borela-Canteli Lemma. Lets take $\epsilon=0.5$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-\epsilon}=\infty$ So $\mathbb{P}(X_n > \epsilon)=1$. So now I can conclude that we don't have almost sure convergence.

Comment: @Prodigy, Yep that's exactly it!